# Two matrix p x m and n x p can not be multiplied because m and n are not equal, what does m,n,and p represent?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

So we can multiply m x p with p x n and we get m x n. Why does this work? Is it because p in m x p equals p in p x n. I'm just trying to understand, what does these variables actually represent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first matrix has $m$ rows and $p$ columns, the second matrix has $p$ rows and $n$ columns.

The entries of the product are calculated by multiplying each row of the first matrix with each column of the second matrix via the dot-product.

This only works, if the numbers of entries coincide. Each row of the first matrix has $p$ entries as well as each column of the second matrix in our case.

The result is a matrix consisting of $m\cdot n$ dot-products of vectors with $p$ entries.

Comment: I thought p in m x p represents the columns not the rows. you mentioned each row of the first matrix has p entries ? Can you clarify

Comment: A $m\times n$-matrix contains $m$ rows with $n$ entries. The first row is $a_{11}\cdots a_{1n}$ , the second row $a_{21}\cdots a_{2n}$ and so on, the last row is $a_{m1}\cdots a_{mn}$. So, the number of entries is $n$